# API Call when a transaction is unconfirmed

Tags: blockchain.info

Is there a way to get blockchain.info API call to know when the network sees an unconfirmed transaction? I'm also interested in any other method to get this result.

The API works fine on the first confirmation but I need a faster method; I can't use bitcoind.

Here's an example that uses chain.so. (I'd prefer to use blockchain.info for all my queries)

here is an address that has 1 BTC unconfirmed transaction by the time of writing:
12gZ9aUaQbu7Pnguot6aKKjuuzQyY15VAE

the API call is : https://chain.so/api/v2/get_address_received/btc/12gZ9aUaQbu7Pnguot6aKKjuuzQyY15VAE

and the output is :

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "network": "BTC",
    "address": "12gZ9aUaQbu7Pnguot6aKKjuuzQyY15VAE",
    "confirmed_received_value": "0.00000000",
    "unconfirmed_received_value": "1.00000000"
  }
}
```

`unconfirmed_recieved_value` is what I need.

Comment: blockchain.info doesn't have a callback for that, unless you're talking about their receive payments API. What do you mean by 'bestchain'? I assume that you're asking about the best blockchain, but you also say that you're asking for something faster than first confirmation.

Comment: bestchain is the longest blockchain that has not been confirmed yet. what I need is a api call that I can check if a transaction has been added to the best chain yet or not, let's say if it's in pre-confirmed state or not.

Comment: Blocks are not confirmed - blocks confirm transactions.

Comment: I may had some mistakes with my wording but what I mean is that when a transaction is seen by the network.

Comment: Also - do you want this to trigger on any transaction, or just to transactions to one of your addresses?

Comment: If there would be a way to query on an address to see if there is an unconfirmed amount on the account, that's what I need. I added an example to the question